# Error while trying to create table in MSSQL using flat-file import

Tags: sql-server, import-from-excel, ssms-2014

I am trying to import a .csv file to SQL Server Native 11.0 in order to create a table.

However, I am getting the following error:

- Warning 0x80070020: Data Flow Task 1: The process cannot access the file 
  because it is bein gused by another process.
- Error 0xc020200e: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot open the datafile

[image]
[image]

Following the the .csv data:

[image]

Need help in figuring out the solution for these errors.

Comment: try closing the file before import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue: This was happening because I have opened the .csv file in excel and at the same time I was trying to import it to SQL Server.

Solution: Try closing the file before importing. It should work then, as it worked for me.